# Clone Serializable Object - JAVA

Tags: java, serialization

I am learning [how to clone serializable object](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.1/org/apache/commons/lang/SerializationUtils.java#SerializationUtils.clone%28java.io.Serializable%29). When I see the code I got confused that why we need to first `serialize` the `object` and then `deserialize` it ? Is it due to we want to get an `Object` (or any other reason) ? Then why we just not return the `object` or `serialize` object ?

```
public static Object clone(Serializable object) {
   return deserialize(serialize(object));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Source](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-perform-a-deep-clone-using-serializable.html)

> The (simple) clone() method of Object performs a shallow copy of an object.
>   This means that primitive fields are copied, but objects within the
>   cloned object are not copied. Rather, the references within the new
>   object point to the objects referenced by the original object. This
>   can sometimes lead to unexpected results. Sometimes a deep copy of an
>   object is needed. In a deep copy, rather than references in the new
>   object pointing to the same objects as the original class, the
>   references point to new objects (whose values have been copied over).

That's why for deep cloning we first `serialize` (to copy primitive and non-primitive type objects) and then `deserialize` (to get and return object from bytes) the `object` so that we get every thing within the `object` not just primitive type.

Answer (score 1):

If the `object` itself was returned it will not be a clone of the `object` it will just be the same object so `object` can not be returned.

And the `serialize` can not be returned because the return type of `clone()` is `Object` and the return type of `serialize()` is `byte[]`.

So in a nutshell the `clone()` method serializes the `object` into `byte` array by calling `serialize(object)` and then converts that `byte` array into a `object` by calling `deserialize()` with it. It results in a `new Object` with the same properties as the `object`.